# How do I show if an integral converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I am trying to do the comparison lemma on 2 integrals, and I need to evaluate the following integral for all $p \gt0$, or show the integral diverges.
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{x(\ln(\frac{1}{x}))^p}dx = \left [\frac{-\ln x}{(p-1)(-\ln x)^p} \right]_{0}^{{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

How do I do this? I know that I will need to do a substitution using $u=-\ln x$, giving me $dx=-x~du$. However, when I change the limits in the substitution, $-\ln 0$ is undefined, is this sufficient to show that the integral diverges?

Update: I currently have

$$\frac{(\ln 2)^{1-p}}{p-1} + \lim_{k \to 0^+} \left(\frac{\ln k}{(p-1)(-\ln k)^p} \right)$$

and I am stuck on the conclusion. Is it because $ \ln 0$ diverges, hence the integral diverges?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should replace 0 by $\epsilon > 0$, do the computations and then take the limit.

Comment: @blamethelag does that mean i need to rewrite the integral as $\lim_{k \to 0+}$ and change the bottom boundary into k?

Comment: Yes indeed it is what I meant

Comment: @blamethelag so the integral converges for all p>0 am I right?

Comment: I don't think so. What does the computation give?

Comment: @blamethelag please see edited post